# Using Bootstrap 3 embed-responsive-21by9 it doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 on embed element if use 'embed-responsive-16by9' it properly work. But if I use 'embed-responsive-21by9' it doesn't work! Why? How can I fix it?

This works:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
    <div id="map_detail" class="map embed-responsive-item" ></div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9" >
    <div id="map_detail" class="map embed-responsive-item" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your code that you have

Comment: Code posted. @mlegg

Comment: What do you have for the css for id="map_detail"

Comment: nothing. It is a openlayer3 map.

Comment: It's could be a bootsrap version issue? 21:9 ratio is implemented on version 3? @mlegg

Comment: No 16 to 9 is and so is 4 to 3

Answer (score 1):

I add this on css and it work:

```
   .embed-responsive-21by9 {
    padding-bottom:42.85%;
    }
```